# Swift get location THEN load table

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cllocationmanager, uicollectionviewcell, cllocation

So I want to ask a user for their location when they open the app for the first time and THEN load the table. Here's my present code:

```
class LayoutController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
APIControllerProtocol, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var chainTable: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var navLogo: UIButton!
    let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var lat: String = "lat!"
    var long: String = "long!"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
        navLogo.userInteractionEnabled = false

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways){
            var currentLocation = locationManager.location
            var longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
            var latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude

            long = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
            lat = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.            
        loadTable(lat, longitude, long)
    }

    func loadTable(latitude: String, longitude: String){
        api = APIController(delegate: self)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        api!.getPosts(latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

The data doesn't properly load on the first download and after location is enabled. I does work when you restart the app however. How can I make the table check if the location is given before loading?  Thanks.

(I have tried it with the loadTable function inside the `if CLLocationManager.authorizationstatus()...` block to no avail either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dimpiax suggests, you're going about this wrong.

The location manager is an asynchronous API. Once you make sure you are authorized to use it, you ask it to start updating your location. Then you wait for it to call your delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

Even then you're not done. Usually the first location you get is old and very, very wrong. (It is the location that was read when the GPS was last active.) You have to check the timestamp on that location and ignore it if it's timestamp is more than a few seconds old.

But wait, you're **still** not done. Once you've thrown away a possible out-of-date location, you need to wait until the GPS settles down and starts giving decent readings. For the first 5 or more seconds after you ask for location updates, the margin of error on the readings is usually very bad. You figure this out by checking the horizontal accuracy property on the location record you get. The value is actually a radius. Large numbers are bad, small numbers are good. You probably want a reading with a horizontal accuracy of <= 100 meters.

Once you've got that, you're ready to reload your table view.

Comment: So is that a whole other method that I need to add or just another line? Thanks

Comment: Also, I have never seen any other application that had anywhere close to a 5 second load time even after the first download

Comment: A whole other method. You need to implement the location manager delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out already. I'll check you off and post my code. :) cheers

Comment: I was talking about how long it takes the GPS to settle down and give accurate readings. Sometimes it's more like 15 or more seconds. What you do what that fact is up to you. It's probably not a good idea to not display anything. Our location app, SaveMyPlace, tells you the horizontal accuracy of the location signal as the location updates arrive. You can see the blue dot start out pretty far from your actual location and then get closer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to listen the delegation method of **CLLocationManagerDelegate**:

```
locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
```

and there after successful result got, set and reload data of table view.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to Duncan and [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSjbMwR2A2U)

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil){
            println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark

            if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways){
                var currentLocation = self.locationManager.location
                var longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                var latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude

                self.long = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
                self.lat = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)
            }

            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            self.loadTable(self.lat, longitude: self.long)
        }else{
            println("error with data")
        }

    })
```

I added it right below viewDidLoad and moved that `Auth` block into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class to fetch the user's current location and return it in a block.

```
class NACurrentLocationTrackManager: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
     private static var privateShared : NACurrentLocationTrackManager?
    typealias completionHandler = (_ location: CLLocation?,_ error: String?) -> Void
    var completion: completionHandler?
    class func shared() -> NACurrentLocationTrackManager {
    guard let uwShared = privateShared else {
        privateShared = NACurrentLocationTrackManager()
        return privateShared!
    }
    return uwShared
}
class func destroy() {
    privateShared = nil
}
func stopLocationManager() {
    locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
func startMonitoringLocationWithBlock(handler:@escaping (_ location: CLLocation?,_ error: String?) -> Void){
    self.completion = handler
    if locationManager == nil{
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}
func restartMonitoringLocation(){
    locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways ||  CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied{
        logh("Location service is disable")
        NAAppHelper.showLocationPermissionAlert()
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }else{
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let location = locations.last
    if let handler = completion {
        handler(location, nil)
    }
    stopLocationManager()
}
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        if let handler = completion {
            handler(nil, "")
        }
    }
 }
And to fetch the location, use this code in your viewcontroller:
    NACurrentLocationTrackManager.shared().startMonitoringLocationWithBlock { (location, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print(location)
        }
    }
```